# Customize grep option according the output of URL

Tags: grep

I want to be find the updated Kernel version using `curl` command and local kernel version using `grep` and `uname -r` commands.

```
curl -s https://api.linode.com/v4/linode/kernels/linode/latest-64bit | grep "Latest 64 bit *$(uname -r)"
```

Here are my each command output

Command

```
curl -s https://api.linode.com/v4/linode/kernels/linode/latest-64bit
```

Output of above command

```
{"label": "Latest 64 bit (4.14.12-x86_64-linode92)", "kvm": true, "id": "linode/latest-64bit", "pvops": true, "architecture": "x86_64", "xen": true, "version": "4.14.12"}
```

Command

```
uname -r
```

Command Output

```
4.14.12-x86_64-linode92
```

I want help about about the `curl output of Linode API` and `grep expression` working together.

When a Kernel update is available using Linode API URL and i would like to compare using grep command with the Linode API URL.

Comment: what is your exact expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to use `grep` is a mystery to me.
Your desired output would probably be:

```
curl -s https://api.linode.com/v4/linode/kernels/linode/latest-64bit | sed 's/.*(//;s/).*/\n/;'
4.14.12-x86_64-linode92
```

and an comparison would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
thiskernel=$(uname -r)
latest=$(curl -s https://api.linode.com/v4/linode/kernels/linode/latest-64bit | sed 's/.*(//;s/).*/\n/;')
if [ "$latest" = "$thiskernel" ] ; then
    echo "Running the latest kernel $latest"
else
    echo "Whoah! check it out! there is a new kernel $latest,"
    echo " and you are running an old legacy $thiskernel"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a for info but i want to add `reboot` when new kernel update is available using above script..